# Unable to link page to the other pages with two navigation bar in the same page

Tags: html, css

anyone can help me? I have two different navigation bar in a page that going to link the page to the other page. But two of them was located in different location which is one is on the top and another one is on the bottom.

*For the bottom part I just replaced my navigation bar’s coding with “b href”for temporary and would like to ask for your solution”

Below is my coding:

On top of the page (navigation bar coding)

```
  <label for="home" class="home"><a href=" "><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a ></label>

  <label for="tours" class="tours"><a href="tours.html"><i class="fas fa-route"></i>Tours</a ></label>

  <label for="destination" class="destination"><a href="destination.html"><i class="fas fa-plane-arrival"></i>Destination</a ></label>

 <label for="aboutus" class="aboutus"><a href="aboutus.html"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>About Us</a ></label>

 <label for="contact" class="contact"><a href="contact.html"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Contact</a ></label>
```

bottom part of the page (navigation bar coding)
(I understand that there isn’t any hyperlink called “b href” so I just replaced it temporary

```
    <li><b href="#" class="homebottom">Home</b></li>
        <li><b href="destination.html">Destination</b></li>[enter image description here][1]
        <li><b href="tours.html">Tours</b></li>
        <li><b href="aboutus.html">About Us</b></li>
        <li><b href="contact.html">Contact</b></li>

    </ul>
```

Conclusion: How do I style two navigation bar without affecting the existing one?

[bottom part navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE239.jpg)

[top part navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjVUR.jpg)

Comment: Can you please say your question in a better way? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hi, actually I have two different navigation bar in a page which located at different position. One of the navigation bar I’d successfully link the page to the other pages with using “a href” but the other navigation bar because is different location so I must declare in different “div” which is “b href” but the navigation bar unable to link the pages together. Is there any other way  that I can link another navigation bar with the different coding?

Comment: How do I style two navigation bar without affecting the already existing one?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `id` to the navigation elements that are unique, such as `topNav` and `bottomNav`. Then you can use the unique ID to target different elements with different css.

```
<ul id="topNav">
...
<ul id="bottomNav">

ul#topNav {}
ul#bottomNav {}
```

This technique is sometimes referred to as pseudo-namespacing.